# How can I add HTML to a jQuery tooltip?

Tags: jquery, jquery-tools

I am trying to setup tooltips on my page. There are 7 links in a list that all have tooltips. 6 of these just uses the basic setup but one of them needs to use the larger background image and have custom HTML. When I try to configure this the 6 basic tooltips work but nothing happens for the 1 larger HTML one.

Here is my code:

```
    <tr><td>
    <a class="text_link" title="Tooltip text">Dental Insurance Providers</a>
</td></tr>
<tr><td>
    <a class="text_link" id="health_insurance_tooltip" >Health Insurance Providers</a>
    <div class="tooltip">           
        <a href="#">This is my html tooltip</a>
    </div>
</td></tr>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // initialize tooltip
    $("[title]").tooltip({ 
        position: "top left", 
        effect: 'slide',
        opacity: 1,
        offset: [15, 190],
        tipClass: 'small_tooltip'
        });

     $("#health_insurance_tooltip").tooltip({ 
        position: "top left", 
        effect: 'slide',
        opacity: 1,
        offset: [15, 190]
        });
</script>

<style type="text/css">
/* tooltip styling  */
.small_tooltip {
    display:none;
    background:url(/fcapps/images/tooltip/white_arrow.jpg);
    font-size:12px;
    height:70px;
    width:160px;
    padding:25px;
    color:#255E0D;  
    opacity:1 !important;
    }

.tooltip {
    display:none;
    background:url(/fcapps/images/tooltip/white_arrow_big.png);
    font-size:12px;
    height:70px;
    width:160px;
    padding:25px;
    color:#255E0D;  
    opacity:1;
}
</style>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try embedding the html in the title tag rather than having it as a standalone div. It's a little inconvenient since you have to escape any quotes that appear in your HTML, but it has worked for me. So replace:

```
<a class="text_link" id="health_insurance_tooltip" >Health Insurance Providers</a>
<div class="tooltip">           
    <a href="#">This is my html tooltip</a>
</div>
```

With:

```
<a class="text_link" id="health_insurance_tooltip"
    title="This is my <i>html</i> tooltip">Health Insurance Providers</a>
```